# Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible Server: pg_restore produces pg_catalog ACL privilege warnings

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-pipelines, pg-restore, azure-postgresql

I am using Azure DevOps Pipelines in order to copy databases from one [Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/overview) (in my prod environment) to another Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible Server (in my testing environment) by means of `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`.

More precisely I do a

```bash
pg_dump -d ${MY_PROD_CONNECTION_STRING} -Fc > my_prod_db.dump
```

followed by a

```bash
pg_restore -d ${MY_TESTING_CONNECTION_STRING} --clean --if-exists --create --verbose my_prod_db.dump
```

The user specified in my connection strings is the Flexible Servers' admin user (set in the ARM Template) and, thus, should have all necessary permissions.

The restore seems to work and all my data in the schemas `dms`, `erp`, `rm`, and `wm` is restored successfully. However, I get an awful lot of ACL privilege warnings for `pg_catalog` which makes my pipeline fail:

```
2022-10-19T14:42:46.4612084Z Restoring database my_prod_db from backup file...
2022-10-19T14:42:46.5030988Z pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
2022-10-19T14:42:46.5357570Z pg_restore: dropping DATABASE my_prod_db
2022-10-19T14:42:46.5362470Z pg_restore: creating DATABASE "my_prod_db"
2022-10-19T14:42:46.6785620Z pg_restore: connecting to new database "my_prod_db"
2022-10-19T14:42:46.7119333Z pg_restore: creating SCHEMA "dms"
2022-10-19T14:42:46.7165532Z pg_restore: creating SCHEMA "erp"
2022-10-19T14:42:46.7297408Z pg_restore: creating SCHEMA "rm"
2022-10-19T14:42:46.7346145Z pg_restore: creating SCHEMA "wm"
[...]
2022-10-19T14:42:54.9711464Z pg_restore: creating ACL "DATABASE my_prod_db"
2022-10-19T14:42:54.9761556Z pg_restore: creating ACL "SCHEMA dms"
2022-10-19T14:42:54.9799417Z pg_restore: creating ACL "SCHEMA erp"
2022-10-19T14:42:54.9841884Z pg_restore: creating ACL "SCHEMA public"
2022-10-19T14:42:54.9877636Z pg_restore: creating ACL "SCHEMA rm"
2022-10-19T14:42:54.9916392Z pg_restore: creating ACL "SCHEMA wm"
2022-10-19T14:42:54.9960911Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_replication_origin_advance(text, pg_lsn)"
2022-10-19T14:42:54.9980528Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_advance"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0015526Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_replication_origin_create(text)"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0033679Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_create"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0083430Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_replication_origin_drop(text)"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0111392Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_drop"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0139577Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_replication_origin_oid(text)"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0169206Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_oid"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0194763Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_replication_origin_progress(text, boolean)"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0212578Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_progress"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0238129Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_replication_origin_session_is_setup()"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0253859Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_session_is_setup"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0280327Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_replication_origin_session_progress(boolean)"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0300701Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_session_progress"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0350099Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_replication_origin_session_reset()"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0364519Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_session_reset"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0392970Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_replication_origin_session_setup(text)"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0411620Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_session_setup"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0440686Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_replication_origin_xact_reset()"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0461386Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_xact_reset"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0483750Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_replication_origin_xact_setup(pg_lsn, timestamp with time zone)"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0504906Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_replication_origin_xact_setup"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0533793Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_show_replication_origin_status(OUT local_id oid, OUT external_id text, OUT remote_lsn pg_lsn, OUT local_lsn pg_lsn)"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0551684Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_show_replication_origin_status"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0604569Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_stat_reset()"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0623983Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_stat_reset"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0653638Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_stat_reset_shared(text)"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0672543Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_stat_reset_shared"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0701706Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_stat_reset_single_function_counters(oid)"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0721271Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_stat_reset_single_function_counters"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0747751Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.FUNCTION pg_stat_reset_single_table_counters(oid)"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.0762384Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_stat_reset_single_table_counters"
[...]
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4147229Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_config.name"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4211520Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "name" of relation "pg_config"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4239955Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_config.setting"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4259742Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "setting" of relation "pg_config"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4288947Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_hba_file_rules.line_number"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4299663Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "line_number" of relation "pg_hba_file_rules"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4333256Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_hba_file_rules.type"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4344203Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "type" of relation "pg_hba_file_rules"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4380293Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_hba_file_rules.database"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4402651Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "database" of relation "pg_hba_file_rules"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4434328Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_hba_file_rules.user_name"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4446740Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "user_name" of relation "pg_hba_file_rules"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4479568Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_hba_file_rules.address"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4497457Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "address" of relation "pg_hba_file_rules"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4537733Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_hba_file_rules.netmask"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4577213Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "netmask" of relation "pg_hba_file_rules"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4624513Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_hba_file_rules.auth_method"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4643516Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "auth_method" of relation "pg_hba_file_rules"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4671263Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_hba_file_rules.options"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4690626Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "options" of relation "pg_hba_file_rules"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4720235Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_hba_file_rules.error"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4734431Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "error" of relation "pg_hba_file_rules"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4764105Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_replication_origin_status.local_id"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4781665Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "local_id" of relation "pg_replication_origin_status"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4827357Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_replication_origin_status.external_id"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4851279Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "external_id" of relation "pg_replication_origin_status"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4870543Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_replication_origin_status.remote_lsn"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4884410Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "remote_lsn" of relation "pg_replication_origin_status"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4916783Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_replication_origin_status.local_lsn"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4931102Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "local_lsn" of relation "pg_replication_origin_status"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4961582Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_shmem_allocations.name"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.4983419Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "name" of relation "pg_shmem_allocations"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5010474Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_shmem_allocations.off"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5024307Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "off" of relation "pg_shmem_allocations"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5068707Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_shmem_allocations.size"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5079786Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "size" of relation "pg_shmem_allocations"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5118761Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_shmem_allocations.allocated_size"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5135015Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "allocated_size" of relation "pg_shmem_allocations"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5169611Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.starelid"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5192635Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "starelid" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5222031Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.staattnum"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5234193Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "staattnum" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5265363Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stainherit"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5285118Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stainherit" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5317179Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stanullfrac"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5350956Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stanullfrac" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5361487Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stawidth"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5380531Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stawidth" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5407709Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stadistinct"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5417900Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stadistinct" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5449337Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stakind1"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5463215Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stakind1" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5491601Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stakind2"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5504553Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stakind2" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5534905Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stakind3"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5548265Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stakind3" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5583660Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stakind4"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5593730Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stakind4" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5624020Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stakind5"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5639925Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stakind5" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5665472Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.staop1"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5675929Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "staop1" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5707356Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.staop2"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5721775Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "staop2" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5750889Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.staop3"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5774344Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "staop3" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5796088Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.staop4"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5804802Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "staop4" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5837555Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.staop5"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5850872Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "staop5" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5886260Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stacoll1"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5922844Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stacoll1" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5948442Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stacoll2"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5954320Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stacoll2" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.5996633Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stacoll3"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6003344Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stacoll3" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6034555Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stacoll4"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6042181Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stacoll4" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6080838Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stacoll5"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6092578Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stacoll5" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6140105Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stanumbers1"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6155468Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stanumbers1" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6191753Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stanumbers2"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6249200Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stanumbers2" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6278461Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stanumbers3"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6289179Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stanumbers3" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6320451Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stanumbers4"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6335628Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stanumbers4" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6363524Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stanumbers5"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6380836Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stanumbers5" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6427378Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stavalues1"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6428014Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stavalues1" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6449984Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stavalues2"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6461145Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stavalues2" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6491503Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stavalues3"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6509484Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stavalues3" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6542533Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stavalues4"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6576352Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stavalues4" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6602362Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_statistic.stavalues5"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6615498Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "stavalues5" of relation "pg_statistic"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6643852Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_subscription.oid"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6655498Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "oid" of relation "pg_subscription"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6685812Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_subscription.subdbid"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6697693Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "subdbid" of relation "pg_subscription"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6729469Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_subscription.subname"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6740600Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "subname" of relation "pg_subscription"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6769088Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_subscription.subowner"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6786594Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "subowner" of relation "pg_subscription"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6816823Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_subscription.subenabled"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6833332Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "subenabled" of relation "pg_subscription"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6870417Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_subscription.subconninfo"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6895329Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "subconninfo" of relation "pg_subscription"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6909271Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_subscription.subslotname"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6943704Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "subslotname" of relation "pg_subscription"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6948623Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_subscription.subsynccommit"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6967127Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "subsynccommit" of relation "pg_subscription"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.6995473Z pg_restore: creating ACL "pg_catalog.COLUMN pg_subscription.subpublications"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.7012958Z pg_restore: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for column "subpublications" of relation "pg_subscription"
[...]
2022-10-19T14:42:55.8680669Z pg_restore: creating DEFAULT ACL "dms.DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR TABLES"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.8719540Z pg_restore: creating DEFAULT ACL "erp.DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR TABLES"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.8758216Z pg_restore: creating DEFAULT ACL "rm.DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR TABLES"
2022-10-19T14:42:55.8793094Z pg_restore: creating DEFAULT ACL "wm.DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR TABLES"
```

The same warnings also appear when I try the alternative approach (avoiding `--clean` and `--create` just in case):

```
pg_dump -d ${MY_PROD_CONNECTION_STRING} -Fc > my_prod_db.dump

az postgres flexible-server db delete --resource-group my-rg --server-name psql-mycompanyapp-testing --database-name my_prod_db --yes
az postgres flexible-server db create --resource-group my-rg --server-name psql-mycompanyapp-testing --database-name my_prod_db

pg_restore -d ${MY_TESTING_CONNECTION_STRING} --exit-on-error --verbose my_prod_db.dump
```

1. What is the reason for these warnings? Both Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible Servers were created from the same ARM Template and should be identical.
2. Can I safely ignore the warnings or how should I deal with it?

I already created a [Github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/100198) with Microsoft Documentation, but have not gotten any help so far.

Comment: Any solution on this ? I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have the same warning.

I then tested login both using postgres (cloudsqlsuperuser) and another admin who is a cloudsqlsuperuser as well, calling this say:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_replication_origin_advance("sas2json", "28/160E2250");
```

The function can be accessed by both it just complains the column `sas2json` does not exist so I know I can safely ignore the warning.

However, no clues why the warning.